# How to tell gnome which file to use to change backlight brightness?

Tags: 10.04, brightness, backlight, gnome-power-manager

I have a Dell Inspiron M5010 and I am unable to change my backlight brightness with the F-Keys and it also does not work with gnome brightness widget.

I am able to change backlight brightness manually on the terminal with

```
$ sudo -s
$ cd /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/dell_backlight
$ ls -la
  insgesamt 0
  drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 2012-04-06 13:03 .
  drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 2012-04-06 13:03 ..
  -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-04-06 13:17 actual_brightness
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-04-06 13:17 bl_power
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-04-06 13:03 brightness
  -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-04-06 13:03 max_brightness
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 2012-04-06 13:17 power
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2012-04-06 13:03 subsystem -> ../../../../class/backlight
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-04-06 13:03 uevent
$ echo 8 > brightness
```

Can I configure gnome power manager to use the right files somehow?

Comment: did you try adding 'ACPI_BACKLIGHT=VENDOR' to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub ??

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for closure. Thanks!